# php mysql update prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

hey my database does nothing and i dont know why.

the code

```
$blub = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `aufträge` SET status= ? WHERE id= ?");
$blub->bindParam(1, $m[0]);
$blub->bindParam(2, $m[1]);
$blub->execute();      `

var_dump($blub);
```

> object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(43) "UPDATE
>   `aufträge` SET status= ? WHERE id= ?" }

data base does nothing.
if i dont use prepared statements it runs without a problem

please help me, i want to use prepared statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out : ( I believe you were using `mysqli` syntax)

```
$blub = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `aufträge` SET status= :status WHERE id= :id"); 
$blub->bindParam(':status', $m[0]); 
$blub->bindParam(':id', $m[1]); 
$blub->execute();
```

Also make sure that `$m[0]` and `$m[1]` are set when you are passing them to the query (in a loop or whatnot)

Comment: i've alredy tried.... thank you 4 quick answer
var_dump shows `object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(51) "UPDATE `aufträge` SET status= :status WHERE id= :id" }`
and $m is set! var dump shows 

     array(2) { [0]=> &string(5) "28136" [1]=> &string(14) "in Bearbeitung" }

in the same script i use 

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT PSW, level, name FROM USER WHERE id = :idd LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->bindParam(':idd', $id);
        $stmt->execute(); 
    for login, and it works....

Comment: i connect like this
`  $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1';
  $user = 'root';
  $password = '';
  try {
      $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }                                   
    `